# Dihedral angle calculation in pyramid with square base ABCD.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let OABCD be a pyramid with square base ABCD such that the angle between lateral edge OA and OB,the angle between lateral edge OB and OC,the angle between lateral edge OC and OD,the angle between lateral edge OD and OA is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.Then what is the angle between the planes OAB and OBC,what is the angle between the planes OAB and ABC,and what is the volume of the pyramid.

EDIT 1:The sides OA=OB=OC=OD=1 unit

I dont have working knowledge of pyramids.Can someone please guide me how can i find the angle between lateral faces and angle between a lateral face and the base if the angle between the lateral edges is given.

Comment: To find the volume you must have the measure of some edge, not only angles.

Comment: Concerning *dihedral* angles

Comment: yes dihedral angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle between two planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$, having a line of intersection $r$, is defined as the angle formed by two lines $a\subset \alpha$ and $b\subset\beta$, both perpendicular to $r$ at the same point $M$.

In your case, to find the angle between $OAB$ and $OBC$ you can for instance draw the altitudes $AM$ and $CM$ of those two faces: then the angle is $\angle AMC$. To compute it you can find the lengths of $AM$, $CM$ and $AC$ (by some standard trigonometry) and then use the cosine law to get the angle.

The angle between $OAB$ and $ABCD$ is even easier: if $OK$ is another altitude of face $OAB$, then the angle is just $\angle OKH$, where $H$ is the center of square base.

Comment: In the book it is given,if $\theta$ is the angle between OA,OB,OC,OD taken in pair and if $\phi$ is the angle between $OAB$ and $OBC$,then $\sin^2\theta.\cos\phi=(1-\cos\theta)^2$.I did not understand how this relation was derived.@Aretino

Comment: You can derive it by the method I outlined in my answer: I could go into further details but it's far better if you work a little on that. Ask if anything is not clear enough.

Comment: Using trigonometry in triangles OAB and OBC,i found AM and CM are $\sin\theta$ but i could not find $AC$ so that i could use cosine law in triangle AMC(M is meeting point as suggested in your post)@Aretino.

Comment: Side $AB$ is $2\sin(\theta/2)$, so that $AC=\sqrt2 AB=2\sqrt2\sin(\theta/2)$. To recover the result given by your textbook you must use in the end the bisection formula $\sin^2(\theta/2)=(1-\cos\theta)/2$.

Comment: @Diya In isosceles triangle OCD, the angles are $ \pi/4, 3 \pi/8, 3 \pi/8 $ and normal PD is $ \cos \pi/8$. Is this much clear?

Comment: @Narasimham,yes i got it.

Comment: @Narasimham,sir normal PD is coming$\sin \pi/4$.Isn't it?

Comment: No, PD is $ \cos \pi/8 !! $

Comment: When we consider triangle AMC,AM is $\sin\theta$,CM is $\sin\theta$,AC is 2$\sqrt2 \sin(\theta/2)$.Applying cosine law,\cos\phi=\frac{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\theta-8\sin^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin^2\theta}=-\tan^2(\theta/2),but book says $\cos\phi=\tan^2(\theta/2)$,but i think we are nowhere wrong.@Aretino,

Comment: Except the sign ! . It should be  $ cos \phi =- tan^{2}  \theta/2$

Comment: Check: for $\theta=\pi/2$ you have $\phi=\pi$, so that $\cos\phi=-1$. So the formula in your book has the wrong sign.

Answer (score 1):

Consider each *face*. Draw a diagram. Angles are $ \pi/4,3 \pi/8,3 \pi/8$ at top of pyramid and base respectively.

Draw a perpendicular onto a slant height side from any base corner (A,B,C or D) to a point labelled P. Its length is $ \cos \pi/8$. There are two such sides either side of  dihedral indicated in a coarse sketch.

EDIT1:

The base of pyramid is taken as a unit square for convenience.

[image: DihedralonPyramid]

Base diameter is $ \sqrt 2$.  Three sides are known, it is SSA case to solve for dihedral.

Use the Cosine Rule, simplify, getting angle

$$ \cos \gamma = -\tan^{2}\frac{\pi}{8},  \; \gamma \approx 99.8793^0 $$

Can you find pyramid height H ? Volume = H/3.

Comment: I did not understand why angle $\frac{3\pi}{8}$ in the first line of your post.Which angle is $\frac{3\pi}{8}?$@Narasimhan

Comment: Why is the length of perpendicular on the slant height side from any base corner (A,B,C or D) is $\cosπ/8$ and base diameter is $\sqrt2$,in this question,base square sides are not given.@Narasimhan.

Comment: I added a rough sketch.Does it clarify or make it more difficult?

Comment: ,sir this diagram is clear but still the doubts posted in above comment still lingers in my mind.

Comment: @Narasimham Lateral edges are of unit length, not base edges.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I shall add it. taking base edge is more convenient than slanted dimension.

Comment: @diya Sorry  I had taken  base of square=1, more conveniently.

Comment: Yes sir,i was thinking that you mistook base as 1.@Narasimham

Comment: Sir both answers are very helpful,dont know whom to tick as most helpful.

Comment: Dont worry about it, when you learn it is already done.